# C++ multiple inheritance and mutiple implementation compiles but crashes

Tags: c++, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

i've come across a strange C++ inheritance pattern I have never seen before:

There are two interface A and B. Each interface has two different implementations, called A1 and A2, B1 and B2, respectively. Furthermore there is an interface AB that inherits from interface A and B, and there are two derived classes AB1 und AB2 that use the implementations A1 and B1, A2 and B2.

The Question is:

If I have a pointer of AB, is there a way to assign a pointer of AB1 or AB2? The following code demonstrates the problem. It can be compiled with g++ 4.6 or later at least, but it produces a seg-fault. If I use a dynamic-cast operator the compiler accepts the assignment from AB1* to AB*.

```
#include <iostream>

// first interface and implementations

struct A
{
        virtual void a() = 0;
};

struct A1 : public A
{
        void a() { std::cout << "A1\n"; };
};

struct A2 : public A
{
        void a() { std::cout << "A2\n"; }
};

// second interface and implementations

struct B
{
     virtual void b() = 0;
};

struct B2 : public B
{
    void b() { std::cout << "B2\n"; }
};

// combining interfaces and implementations

struct AB : public A, public B
{};

struct B1 : public B
{
        void b() { std::cout << "B1\n"; }
};


struct AB1 : public A1, public B1
{};

struct AB2 : public A2, public B2
{};

int main()
{
    AB1* ab1 = new AB1();
    ab1->a();
    ab1->b();  

    AB2* ab2 = new AB2();
    ab2->a();
    ab2->b();

    // this code compiles but doesnt work
    AB* ab;

    ab = dynamic_cast<AB*>(ab1);
    ab->a();
    ab->b();

    ab = dynamic_cast<AB*>(ab2);
    ab->a();
    ab->b();

    return 0;
}
```

My best guess is, that the object layout of AB1, AB2 and AB is different. But then, why does the dynamic cast work?

Can anyone point me to further information about this code pattern?

Many thanks,
schluchtenbummler

Comment: `struct AB` is not in the inheritance hierarchy of either `AB1` or `AB2` (ie. it is not a parent or child of `AB1` or `AB2`).  It seems like at best you could cast to a common ancestor `A*` or `B*`, but casting back down the hierarchy from to a "cousin" like this doesn't seem like it ought to be valid.

Comment: You never check whether the cast succeeds - that's lazy.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `ab1` nor `ab2` can be cast to `AB`.  `dynamic_cast` will return NULL (or nullptr if you're using C++11) when the cast cannot be performed.  You should check `ab` for `nullptr` before attempting to access it.  You said in your question "why does the dynamic cast work?"...  The answer is, it does not work, but you didn't check the return value to see if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `dynamic_cast<AB*>(x)` will be `0` if `x` is a pointer to an object whose dynamic type is not `AB` or a type derived thereof. Since `AB` may be injected somewhere later in the inheritance graph and `dynamic_cast` can be use to cast across hierarchies if the concrete object inherits them using multiple inheritance, the compiler has no reason to assume that the pounters don't point to an object which could be an `AB`.